# Actionbar is not showing in Main Activity when navigating back to Main Activity from fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, onbackpressed

I am using Navigation drawer in  my app and I have a toolbar and set it in ActionBar in my Main Activity using below code:

```
setSupportActionBar(mMainActivityToolbar);
```

I have used different toolbar in my fragment and I have set the toolbar from my fragment using the code below:

```
((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(mBinding.fragmentToolbar);
```

I have set back/home button click listener using the below code:

```
// on back button press
mBinding.toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(v -> {
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().show();
    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setActionBarTitle("MainActivity");
    getActivity().onBackPressed();
});

// set up navigation icon
((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

**The problem is when i tap on back button in my actionbar from fragment i popup fragment from backstack but the Mainactivity action bar is not showing up. Should I set main activity's toolbar to the actionbar again?**

**The app is not crashed when i use the above code, but actionbar is not shown**

Comment: Are you somehow changing anything in `ActionBar` within your `Fragment`?

Comment: could you please provide some example? I have used collapsingToolbarLayout in my fragment, whereas i used normal toolbar in my Main activity

Comment: @azizbekian he is definitely changing the `ActionBar` in his fragment. By hiding the first one and setting another one. So after Fragment popup why there will be the old one. It will definitely the new one set in Fragment.

Comment: @Durga, if assumption of Abid Khan is correct - you have to manually set ActionBar again (when your fragment is being closed).

Comment: @Durga you have to set back the old one on Fragment poup. Keep in mind that the Fragment is also using the `MainActivity's` context.

Comment: yes, i have set another toolbar in the fragment. I don't know how to set the main activity toolbar in the actionbar on back press.

Comment: Why do you call .hide() when you are replacing toolbar? Have you tried call .show() when you are returning from your fragment?

Comment: on back press, and there you can change it using your activity's context or some where in changing fragments.

Comment: @TomasIvan yes i have called .show() in main activity's onBackPressed() function. I have called **getSupportActionBar().show();** in onBAckPressed()

Comment: Also @Tomaslvan if i did not call .hide() i get two action bar in my fragment

Comment: You have to manually set it back while popup the fragment like `setSupportActionBar(mainToolbar);`

Comment: Thank you All! setting up the toolbar again `setSupportActionbar(mainToolbar)` worked perfectly.

Comment: Glad to hear that :)